# Extra piece in this double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

I'm asking for help in understanding how to end this exercise. I will write down my procedure, which is incomplete.

> Calculate the area of the region defined by the circumference of centre $C = (1,2)$ and radius $2$, in the interval $[1,2]$

So first of all I wrote down the equation of that circumference, namely

$$(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4$$

that is

$$y = 2 + \sqrt{4 - (x-1)^2}$$

Now this is the function I have to integrate from $1$ to $2$, yet after having sketched the draw of the figure I understood that this area is too much. Indeed there is a piece I have to cut (see the drawing below).

I don't understand how to take it off though...

$$A = \int_1^2 (2 + \sqrt{4 - (x-1)^2})\ \text{d}x - \text{Extra Piece}$$

How to write down the Extra Piece?

Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$y_\pm = 2 \pm \sqrt{4 - (x-1)^2}$$
representing the upper and lower arcs respectively, and the area is then given by
$$A = \int_1^2 (y_+-y_-)dx =\int_1^2 2 \sqrt{4 - (x-1)^2}\ dx=\sqrt3+\frac{2\pi}3$$

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I think I made some mistakes when I tried to plot the lower arc, since it gave me a strange curve (I thought about the minus sign, due to the simmetry, but I also though I was wrong). Thank you!